# how to load a subclass of uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsxmlparser

I have been working on trying to load a subclass of a uitableview for the last few days and have been having various troubles with it. the main one being that the view is loading before any of the data is parsed. but their have been other issues but most of all really is probably my lack of understanding of how to do this, I have done various single view xml parsing from rss feeds as my datasource but never loading different datasources from a parent views cell selection.. which is where the trouble starts to happen, for me anyway.

So I was hoping that someone could help me in the right direction on how best to do this..

Here is my solution so far.

ParentView.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    //--- Idendify selected indexPath (section/row)
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        //--- Get the subview ready for use
        SearchResultsViewController *searchResultsViewController = [[SearchResultsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchResultsViewController" bundle:nil];
        // ...
        //--- Sets the back button for the new view that loads
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:searchResultsViewController animated:YES];

        switch (indexPath.row)
        {
                case 0: searchResultsViewController.title = @"Manufacture";
                [searchResultsViewController setRequestString:@"manufacture.php"]; //sets the request string in searchResultsViewController
                break;

                case 1: searchResultsViewController.title = @"Model";
                break;

                case 2: searchResultsViewController.title = @"Year";
                break;

                case 3: searchResultsViewController.title = @"Key type";
                break;
        }

        //--- Clean up subview
        [searchResultsViewController release];
    }
}
```

So basicly I have this code calling my child tableview, inside the section if statment and then setting the title and the request string in the row if statment.

SearchResultsViewController.m

```
#import "SearchResultsViewController.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"


@implementation SearchResultsViewController

@synthesize itemString;
@synthesize myDataArray;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [myDataArray count];
    NSLog(@"number or rows first = %d", [myDataArray count]);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}

- (IBAction)setRequestString:(NSString *)string
{
    //clear datat
    [myDataArray removeAllObjects];
    //set up address
    NSMutableString *databaseURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8888/CodeTest/"];
    [databaseURL appendString:string];
    //call delegates
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:databaseURL]; //LIVE mode
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{     
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString]; //Pass request text from server over to NSString 
    NSData *capturedResponseData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

    [self startTheParsingProcess:capturedResponseData];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

#pragma mark - Parsing lifecycle
//--- Start parsing process using NSXMLParser ---------------->>
- (void)startTheParsingProcess:(NSData *)parserData
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:parserData]; //incoming parserDatapassed to NSXMLParser delegate which starts parsing process 

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse]; //Starts the event-driven parsing operation.
    [parser release];

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"item"]) {
        // NSLog(@"Found title!");
        itemString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [itemString appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"item"]) {
        //NSLog(@"ended title: %@", itemString);
        [myDataArray addObject:itemString];

        //TODO: Test release on memory consumption etc
        [itemString release];
        itemString = nil;
    }
}
//--- Finish parsing process using NSXMLParser ---------------->>




@end
```

inside this part I have set up the connection method - (IBAction)setRequestString:(NSString *)string which starts up the the connection gets the data and fires it off to the ASIHTTPRequest requestFinished method which then passes the acquiered data off to the NSXMLParser delegates... however this is where it all tends to fall over. well it displays properly but if i put in some NSLogs it showing some weird parsing..

```
#pragma mark - Parsing lifecycle
//--- Start parsing process using NSXMLParser ---------------->>
- (void)startTheParsingProcess:(NSData *)parserData
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:parserData]; //incoming parserDatapassed to NSXMLParser delegate which starts parsing process 

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse]; //Starts the event-driven parsing operation.
    [parser release];

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"item"]) {
        // NSLog(@"Found title!");
        itemString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"step 1 = %@", itemString);
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [itemString appendString:string];
     NSLog(@"step 2 = %@", itemString);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"item"]) {
        //NSLog(@"ended title: %@", itemString);
        [myDataArray addObject:itemString];
         NSLog(@"step 3 = %@", itemString);

        //TODO: Test release on memory consumption etc
        [itemString release];
        itemString = nil;
    }
}
//--- Finish parsing process using NSXMLParser ---------------->>
```

gives this result

```
2011-09-06 14:09:12.921 Code[12060:207] step 2 = (null)
2011-09-06 14:09:12.923 Code[12060:207] step 1 = 
2011-09-06 14:09:12.923 Code[12060:207] step 2 = Honda
2011-09-06 14:09:12.924 Code[12060:207] step 3 = Honda
2011-09-06 14:09:12.926 Code[12060:207] step 2 = (null)
2011-09-06 14:09:12.927 Code[12060:207] step 1 = 
2011-09-06 14:09:12.930 Code[12060:207] step 2 = Nissan
2011-09-06 14:09:12.932 Code[12060:207] step 3 = Nissan
2011-09-06 14:09:12.932 Code[12060:207] step 2 = (null)
2011-09-06 14:09:12.933 Code[12060:207] step 1 = 
2011-09-06 14:09:12.933 Code[12060:207] step 2 = Mitsubishi
2011-09-06 14:09:12.934 Code[12060:207] step 3 = Mitsubishi
2011-09-06 14:09:12.934 Code[12060:207] step 2 = (null)
2011-09-06 14:09:12.935 Code[12060:207] step 1 = 
2011-09-06 14:09:12.936 Code[12060:207] step 2 = Toyota
2011-09-06 14:09:12.937 Code[12060:207] step 3 = Toyota
2011-09-06 14:09:12.938 Code[12060:207] step 2 = (null)
2011-09-06 14:09:12.939 Code[12060:207] step 1 = 
2011-09-06 14:09:12.939 Code[12060:207] step 2 = Mazda
2011-09-06 14:09:12.940 Code[12060:207] step 3 = Mazda
2011-09-06 14:09:13.001 Code[12060:207] step 2 = (null)
```

Which I am just having trouble trying to work through because I have used nsxmlpaser delegates before and cannot figure out why its messed up so am woundering if it is the way I am calling this tableview from the parentview?

after all of this is done and said no tables are loaded on the view... infact when I debug through the program the tableview row method is called before any of the parsing happens and I cannot figure out how to get the parsing stuff to happen before that so my array count will actually load the appropriate amount of rows.

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your problem - but pushing your view controller should be the very last thing you do in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: nope didnt make a difference :( dose it look like I am doing the right thing though? I havent done thing parent child tableview thing before so its kinda new to me.

Comment: I have just debugged my whole tableview and the data is defiantly being parsed after the view load and goes through all of the table delegates... I need to my head around getting the delegate stuff to b executed first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your setRequestString action is attached to a search button or some such like - which is pressed after the SearchTableViewController has been pushed onto the navigation controller?

If so, the table view delegate methods are called when the view is first loaded, so you will need to refresh the table after your call to

```
[parser parse]
```

by putting a call to

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

to trigger the reload of your table view cells.

i.e.

```
- (void)startTheParsingProcess:(NSData *)parserData
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:parserData]; //incoming parserDatapassed to NSXMLParser delegate which starts parsing process 

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse]; //Starts the event-driven parsing operation.
    [parser release];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: nope, still did not load the number of rows based off **return [myDataArray count];**

Comment: I am starting to think there is something fundamentaly wrong in my parsing process that I need to figure out. as when I check the value of myDataArray with count I get a return of null

Comment: You do have an actual tableview attached to your view controller in your nib I assume - and that table view has its data source and delegates connected to the table view controller?   What are you seeing - an empty table or a blank screen?  Also when you log 'number of rows first' what is showing up - and is it being displayed twice? (once on load, once on the search?)

Comment: Also note in your code above - your NSLog statement in the numberOfRowsInSection is AFTER the return statement so this log statement will never get hit.

Comment: sorry for the late replay was sick all yesterday, yes I have a tableview and datasource and delegates are all hooked up. I am seeing the view load properly but only the background no table.

Comment: I added the  **NSLog(@"%d", [myDataArray count]);** and it appears to be loading twice with the **[self.tableView reloadData];** and only once when I comment it out.. so there must be something wrong with the way I am parsing this stuff as I know for sure the data is coming in on my requestFinished method...

Comment: Is your log message returning a non-zero value for count?  If so then it should be showing something in the table.  I do note that in the example above your cellForRowAtIndexPath does not set any values on the cell, but I assume thats because you've commented this code out for brevity in the question.  Do you actually see a table in the view with empty cells or just completely blank?